# Problems with github dependency imagepicker

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Hi guys this is my first time asking question here but i used to solve a lot of problems checking this site.
can someone help me ? I want to choose an image in my gallery and charge it when i click on a button. For that i am using github imagepciker dependency here https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker.

I first copy past the gradle dependency and now my gradle project look like this

I have to delete some link in the error because of my reputation  being under 10

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            mavenCentral()
    
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"
        }
    }
```

then when I copy past this
implementation `com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1`
or this
implementation `com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1`
or both, i get an error and it say

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/dhaval2404/imagepicker/2.1/imagepicker-2.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/dhaval2404/imagepicker/2.1/imagepicker-2.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dhaval2404/imagepicker/2.1/imagepicker-2.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

Does someone know what to do to solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

For me I have added this below code at settings.gradle file

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soongoing to shut down soon
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using kotlin , you need to add `androidx` dependencies in your `build.gradle (app)`

i.e use

```
implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1'
```

in your app level `build.gradle` and do not disturb project level gradle files